# WPF ListView remove mouseover higligth

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a WPF Listview containing another UserControl. It works fine, but I cannot remove the mouse blu highlight and selected.

Here the code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border
                     BorderBrush="Transparent"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Width="Auto" Margin="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ElementViewModel}" x:Key="ElementTemplate">
        <vw:ElementView />
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>

<GroupBox Header="{x:Static Translate:Translate.CreateLoop}">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ElementList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ElementTemplate}"
              Background="{StaticResource EnvLayout}"
              BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Resources>
                     <!--Foreground for Selected ListViewItem--> 
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                     <!--Background for Selected ListViewItem--> 
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemBackgroundHover" Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>


</GroupBox>
```

the datatemplate is used to bind the view with the corresponding viewmodel.
Here the mouse over style I'd like to remove

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Add a style

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                    />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Remove your style and instead

```
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, in contrast to many other answers on StackOverflow (although I moved the template from `Resources` to `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`->`Style`)